# Trouble Setting Up React and running npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

I am getting the error `Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation. If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to  enable parsing.` when I go to run npm run dev. I am very new to React and have limited knowledge; I am currently following a tutorial and got lost setting up the React. In my 'presets' section, I already have @babel/preset-react in there, so I don't know why the error is occurring or how to fix it.

Here is my babel.config.JSON:

```
  
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "10"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

ERROR:

```
Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    at Parser._raise (C:\Users\andrew.bregman\Documents\AppDev\reactUI\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:775:17)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (C:\Users\andrew.bregman\Documents\AppDev\reactUI\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:768:17)
    at Parser.expectOnePlugin (C:\Users\andrew.bregman\Documents\AppDev\reactUI\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9731:18)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\andrew.bregman\Documents\AppDev\reactUI\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11106:22)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\andrew.bregman\Documents\AppDev\reactUI\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10689:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (C:\Users\andrew.bregman\Documents\AppDev\reactUI\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10669:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\andrew.bregman\Documents\AppDev\reactUI\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10647:23)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (C:\Users\andrew.bregman\Documents\AppDev\reactUI\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10504:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\andrew.bregman\Documents\AppDev\reactUI\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10478:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (C:\Users\andrew.bregman\Documents\AppDev\reactUI\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10441:21)
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-35
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I listed the error in the main post. I can paste the whole error. Error is coming from when I run npm run dev in the terminal @KetZoomer

Comment: Try installing these `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

Comment: @fortunee I just tried this and I got the error that I will update in main

Comment: @AndrewBregman What error?

Comment: @fortunee do you see where I put "Error:"

Comment: @AndrewBregman try renaming your `babel.config.json` file to `.babelrc`

Comment: @fortunee, this worked! But I am getting a warning in DefinePlugin that conflicting values for process.env.NODE_ENV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider renaming you `babel.config.json` file to `.babelrc`

Comment: Is there a way to fix the warning  in DefinePlugin that conflicting values for process.env.NODE_ENV

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: Yes I am @fortunee